# How to use my own Dockerfile to set up a Ray cluster?

Tags: docker, ray

I see how to specify a docker image in ray here: https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/autoscaling.html#common-cluster-configurations

But I have my own Dockerfile in my repository. Is it possible to specify that that Dockerfile get spun up on every instance ray spins up? Is the only solution to push it to an external registry somewhere and specify the image name here?

Answer (score 0):

If you build your own docker image locally using `docker build .`, it is stored in your local docker repository. And when you run autoscaler, it should look up your local repository first before it looks up the external repository.